# Calling a method from a different view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, methods, viewcontroller

I've been exploring virtual card deck randomisation and drawing of cards as a little side hobby recently, and have been focussing on a great tutorial found at [Ontswedder](http://onstwedder.com/Tutorials/Blackjack_Tutorial_for_IOS). However, I've run into a minor issue which I'm hoping you can help me with!

Below, I've included some key aspects of the code for your viewing.

In my **viewController**, I'm wanting to call both the `shuffle` and `draw` methods, found in **Deck.m**. This is possible if I do the following:

```
Deck *d = [[Deck alloc] init];

[d shuffle];
[d deal];
```

However, I need to be able to split these. For example, clicking *one button* initialises the deck, and shuffles it, whilst *another new button* draws a new card (until the deck is empty).

I am having issues with this, and I *could* do the following:

```
Deck *d = [[Deck alloc] init];

[d shuffle];


Deck *d = [[Deck alloc] init];

[d deal];
```

But this is useless to me, as if I call the `init` then a NEW, UNSHUFFLED deck is created and the card is dealt from this new deck.

I've tried declaring `Deck *DeckObject` in **viewController.h**, then simply calling `[DeckObject draw];`, however this provides a null value.

Ultimately, I would like to call these two methods separately. Without needing to `init` a new deck every time if possible!! :-)

I greatly appreciate both everyone's help on this post but also site-wide!

I hope this makes sense, too. Please let me know if you would like more information.
Also, I apologise if any of my terminology is incorrect - still a bit of a newbie!

---

***Included code for context:***

**Card.h**

```
typedef enum {
    Hearts,
    Diamonds,
    Spades,
    Clubs
} Suit;

#define Ace   1
#define Jack  11
#define Queen 12
#define King  13

@interface Card : NSObject {

NSInteger value;
Suit suit;
}

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger value;
@property (nonatomic) Suit suit;

- (id) initWithValue:(NSInteger) aValue suit:(Suit) aSuit;

@end
```

**Card.m**

```
@interface Card(Private)

- (NSString *) valueAsString;
- (NSString *) suitAsString;

@end


@implementation Card

@synthesize value,suit;

- (id) initWithValue:(NSInteger) aValue suit:(Suit) aSuit {
if(self = [super init]) {
    self.value = aValue;
    self.suit = aSuit;
}
return self;
}

- (NSString *) valueAsString {
switch (self.value) {
    case Ace:
        return @"Ace";
        break;
    case Jack:
        return @"Jack";
        break;
    case Queen:
        return @"Queen";
        break;
    case King:
        return @"King";
        break;
    default:
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.value];
        break;
}
}

- (NSString *) suitAsString {
switch (self.suit) {
    case Hearts:
        return @"Hearts";
        break;
    case Diamonds:
        return @"Diamonds";
        break;
    case Spades:
        return @"Spades";
        break;
    case Clubs:
        return @"Clubs";
        break;
    default:
        return nil;
        break;
}
}

- (NSString *) description {
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
        [self valueAsString],
        [self suitAsString]];
}

@end
```

**Deck.h**

```
@interface Deck : NSObject {

@private
NSMutableArray *cards;
}

- (void) shuffle;
- (Card *) draw;
- (NSInteger) cardsRemaining;

@end
```

**Deck.m**

```
@implementation Deck

- (id) init {
if(self = [super init]) {
    cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++) {
        for(int value = 1; value <= 13; value++) {
            Card *card = [[Card alloc] initWithValue:value suit:suit];
            [cards addObject:card];
            [card release];
        }
    }
}
return self;
}


int randomSort(id obj1, id obj2, void *context ) {
// returns random number -1 0 1
return (arc4random()%3 - 1);    
}

- (void) shuffle {
for(int x = 0; x < 500; x++) {
    [cards sortUsingFunction:randomSort context:nil];
}
}

- (Card *) draw {

if([self cardsRemaining] > 0) {
    Card *card = [[cards lastObject] retain];
    [cards removeLastObject];
    return [card autorelease];
}

NSException* myException = [NSException 
exceptionWithName:@"OutOfCardsException"
reason:@"Tried to draw a card from a deck with 0 cards." userInfo:nil]; @throw
myException;
}

- (NSInteger) cardsRemaining {
return [cards count];
}

- (NSString *) description {
NSString *desc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Deck with %d cards\n",[self
cardsRemaining]];
for(int x = 0; x < [self cardsRemaining]; x++) {
    desc = [desc stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n",[[cards objectAtIndex:x]       description]];
}
return desc;
}

- (void) dealloc {
[cards release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but it seems like you just want a Deck property in your view controller which is initialized when the VC initializes, and then you call shuffle and draw at will.  Is there something more to this?

Comment: if you have used this vc then get that instance from self.navigationcontroller.viewcontrollers or else create new instance and access that method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare the property deckObject, that just creates the pointer, you still have to alloc init a Deck object to create an instance.

```
self.deckObject = [[Deck alloc] init];
```

Then, you can use `[self.deckObject shuffle]` and `[self.deckObject deal]`in different button methods.

Comment: Perfect! Looks like that was what I was missing :-)

Comment: However, when I use this method, [self.deckObject deal] is incorrectly drawing a card. Instead of drawing the last card of the array, it is drawing the second last. Any ideas?

Comment: @BenToscano, I don't see anything wrong with the draw method. How do you know it's drawing the second to last? Are you testing on an unshuffled deck?

Comment: I've worked out that when I try to call (for example) NSLog(@"This card is drawn:%@", [self.deckObject deal]) - it was actually calling [self.deckObject deal] and dealing a new card (hence looking as if a card is 'skipped'. Hopefully will be able to work around this.

Answer (score 1):

you have to declaring `Deck *DeckObject` in **viewController.h** as below

```
@interface firstViewController : UIViewController {
    Deck *DeckObject;
}
```

Now in **viewController.m** file's **viewDidLoad** method initialize it like below

```
Deck *DeckObject = [[Deck alloc] init];
```

after that you can call methods in uibutton's action method

```
- (IBAction)BtnShuffle:(id)sender
{
    if (DeckObject) {
        [DeckObject shuffle];
    }
}
```

and

```
- (IBAction)BtnDraw:(id)sender
{
    if (DeckObject) {
        [DeckObject draw];
    }
}
```